# Копирование в буфер обмена на android js

Tags: javascript, android, clipboard

Как скопировать в буфер обмена текст (на `Android`) при помощи `JS`?

Comment: Уточните пожалуйста ваш вопрос

Comment: @alexandrgaiduchok не понимаю что ты еще хочешь узнать детальнее. Челове и так вполне лаконично и четко описал свою задачу.

Answer (score 1):

на чистом js легче использовать внешнюю библиотеку вроде http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ClipboardManager.html

вот пример использования:

```
  ClipboardManager clipboard = (ClipboardManager) getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE); 
  ClipData clip = ClipData.newPlainText(label, text);
  clipboard.setPrimaryClip(clip);
```